# Everytime I run npm install, I get the extraneous warning/error

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

Every single package I install using npm i is extraneous and is not added to package.json. With npm i --save, it will get added but I wonder why this is. I've tested in different directories to make sure the problem is not the parent folder having a node_modules folder.
I'm using node 8.10.0 and npm 3.5.2

[image]

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the only packages that are globally installed are nodemon , npm and sails.
I started using --save  and then it randomly resolved itself after a few minutes.

Comment: seems your Npm is Old. do you need this  specific version of npm. if  yes then you have to add in dependencies by own 
or Update your Npm using  this commend  npm update and install the package  again

Comment: Ok. I ran an update using npm.

Answer (score 0):

So I updated npm using npm, I deleted the local repo and cloned it again, I created test node projects in different directories but the problem persisted.

I'm not sure what stopped it because it resolved on its own after a while, but before that, I was running npm i with --save.